# text size on iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, adaptive-ui

We have an app that originated back on iOS 5.  Our next release will make iOS 7 the minimum, so we haven't used size classes, and we haven't changed our text to use adaptive text.  We did switch to autolayout last year.

We made some modifications and currently under review by Apple.  But we don't have an iPhone 6 Plus to test with.  A user is mentioning that the text is too big.  Is that because we aren't using adaptive text, their app wasn't built with iOS 8, their app doesn't have the iPhone 6 Plus launcher image, or is there more work for us to do?

Comment: Add the iPhone 6 plus launcher image and the text will be 'smaller', but you can test this yourself on the simulator